# How to remove view on touch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a button hooked up in the storyboard to a method `onButtonPress`. In that method I call `[pressedButton removeFromSuperview]` but the view is not removed. I have even tried  `[_scrollView setNeedsDisplay];` and `[_scrollView setNeedsLayout];` with no luck. I am assuming this is a restriction on being able to remove the button I have pressed. Is there a way I can signal to the view controller to call a method in the future to remove this button?

Comment: Have you made sure your button is correctly wired in?

Comment: As a follow up to @Dancreek, `NSLog` your button to make sure it's not `nil`

Answer (score 1):

you can just hide it,

```
- (IBAction)celebritiesButtonPressed:(id)sender {
  self.button.alpha = 0;
  //[self.peopleButton removeFromSuperview]; //as you intend
}
```

Comment: I thought of that but the view is part of a kind of custom table I implemented to avoid using a tableview in a scrollview. So it needs to be removed completely so that I can put all the other views back in place. Basically, I remove all the view in my "table" then add them back with the exception of the one I pressed. Except the one I pressed never gets removed.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, actually. I was making a silly mistake.

The view I was pressing is part of a custom table I implemented to avoid the tableview in the scrollview. What I was doing was removing all the table cells from the table then re-adding them with the exception of the one that was clicked. Except right before I looped through the array which held the views and called `[view removeFromSuperview]`, I removed the view I pressed from that array. Therefore, it was never calling that method. 
So I was doing

```
[_taskViewCells removeObject:t];
for (id taskViewCell in _taskViewsCells) {
    [taskViewCell removeFromSuperview];
    // Remove all the task views
}
```

Pretty silly...